# No class in weka clusters

Tags: cluster-computing, weka, data-mining

I have done clustering using evaluation in a churn value in my dataset. however clusters 1,2,3 have no class although more attributes are assigned in yes/no value. Why is that happening and what does it mean? I didn't understand from other examples.

```
Classes to Clusters:

   0   1   2   3   4  <-- assigned to cluster
 207  86 123  75  93 | No
  85  45  92  93 158 | Yes

Cluster 0 <-- No
Cluster 1 <-- No class
Cluster 2 <-- No class
Cluster 3 <-- No class
Cluster 4 <-- Yes
```